# How to keep other app activity run while my custom toast is display?

Tags: java, broadcastreceiver

How to keep other app activity run while my custom toast is display?

For exemple: when my app receiver `charging broadcast` my custom toast will display and when it run on top other app, other app will pause or stop until custom toast finish.

Any simple code to solve my problem?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand. Can you share a video?

Comment: @Girish more exp: when i play video on Youtube then my custom toast show up the Youtube video will stop. I want is Youtube video didnt stop while my custom toast show up

Comment: Probably Youtube app itself pauses the video when any other view is displayed on top of it. This is similar to when you receive a phone call while watching a video.

Comment: @Girish ok thanks you for simple explain. Also is there a way to ignore that?

Comment: It's totally in YouTube's app control. You should ask YouTube team to ignore that :p